# I have just installed Ubuntu and I cant install any apps

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit

I have just installed Ubuntu onto my laptop as a separate partition to my Windows drive. Everything went fine and all updates were installed. Then I went into the software centre and I can't install any apps it gives me

```
 Package Dependencies cannot be resolved This error could be caused by
 required additional software packages which are missing or not
 installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software
 packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

but nothing else is installing and I cant install any app on the software centre
Any help will be appreciated. I have had a good look around google and couldnt find anything that worked.

Comment: What do you mean by this: 'a separate partition to my windows drive.' Do you have a hard drive specifically made for Windows, and you've installed Ubuntu there, or do you mean you have a Windows partition on a regular hard drive, and you've installed Ubuntu inside that partition??? As for the package installation problem, please post the outputs of 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade' from a terminal window.

Comment: @mikewhatever There are no Windows-only Hard Drives/SSDs/Storage Devices. He meant he has a Drive where Windows is installed, and he made a partition for Ubuntu, Prly The error is self-explanatory , if you have installed anything it has unmet dependencies, or conflicting packages.

Comment: @Uri Herrera Perhaps you should let the OP speak for himself, or is it too much to ask?

Comment: yh icreated a partition on my laptop and installed ubuntu into that, i havnt in stalled anything into ubuntu just the os and the updates

Comment: when i tpyed "sudo apt-get upgrade" i got "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 python-ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
" cant tell u what i got when i typed " sudo apt-get update" codes too long

Answer (score 2):

You must run a repositories update before you can install anything.

To run an update, go to the update manager, and click on Check for updates.

Alternatively, on the terminal type `sudo apt-get update`